# What is ?. in JSX?

Tags: javascript, jsx

I see sometimes in JSX this being using `?.`

For example

```
const featuredImageInfo = {
  url,
  // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
  alt: image?.alt_text,
};
```

I get invalid token unless i remove the `?`. What is it for?

Comment: It's the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: If I remember correctly, that `?` save you to don't get an error in format `image.alt_text not defined`, that means, you will not get an error until the variable has been filled ...

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) but not specific to JSX.

It is safe way to access the nested object properties even if an intermediate property doesn’t exist.

Optional chaining `props?.value` means if the property exist then get the value of that else assign undefined.

```js
const z = {
  test: {
    key: "val"
  }

};

console.log(z.test.key);
console.log(z.test2?.key)
console.log(z.test2.key) // error
```

In the above example you can see while using optional chaining it logs undefined when property does not exist , without it , it throws error

Comment: Interesting thank you! Is there a more traditional way to access object properties if  intermediate property doesn’t exist? Without using `?.`

Answer (score -1):

it's called `Optional Chaining`;) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: Why link to TypeScript's release notes for a JavaScript feature?